Snakeyaml loadAll, modify data, then dumpAll
I'm trying to use snakeyaml to read a yaml file, modify some values, and then write it to another file. I hava multiple documents in 1 file (divided by ---) so I need to use loadAll to read the file and then dumpAll to write it, my issue is I can't get this to work but a simple load and dump works fine (of course I had to remove the multiple documents and keep one only)
Here is the working code using just load and dump if the yaml contains one document only.
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
        .getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("old.yml");
Map<String, Object> data = yaml.load(inputStream);
modifyData(data);
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("new.yml");
yaml.dump(data, writer);

Now here's my implementation when trying to use loadAll and dumpAll, where once I do dumpAll all I get is an empty file.
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
        .getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("old.yml");
Iterable<Object> data = yaml.loadAll(inputStream);

for (Object object : data ) {
    modifyData((Map<String, Object>) object);
}

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("new.yml");
yaml.dumpAll(data.iterator(), writer);


JavaDoc of loadAll reads

Parse all YAML documents in a stream and produce corresponding Java objects. The documents are parsed only when the iterator is invoked.

So the Iterable you get back is not a container that holds your objects, but just a temporary interface to query your data. You need to either:

store the objects in a list when modifying them, then hand that list to dumpAll or
implement an iterator that queries the next object from loadAll, modifies it, then returns it.

